# Conditional parameter while pushing new page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

So far I was able to pass a value to the page that is being pushed using `NavParams`, now the issue is I have to pass a value from lets say page A to page B only if a condition is fulfilled on page A. Previously to pass a single value I used the below code, which works:

```
addNewContact(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.navCtrl.push(EditContactPage, {
      isAdd: "true",
    });
}
```

I tried the below code to pass another value:

```
addNewContact(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.navCtrl.push(EditContactPage, {
      isAdd: "true",
      if(isLocal) {
      isLocalContact : "true"   // ERROR: Unused Label.
      }
   });
}
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that not throwing some sort of syntax error?

Comment: @suraj: No just a red swirly line under `isLocalContact` that says Unused Label.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write `if` statement inside the object assignation. So you can go with using `ternary operators`.

Try this below code.

```
 this.navCtrl.push(EditContactPage, {
      isAdd: "true",
      isLocalContact : isLocal ? "true" : "false"
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Object cannot add properties like that, you have to do something like the following:

```
addNewContact(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();

  const navObj = {
    isAdd: "true"
  };
  if (isLocal) {
    navObj.isLocalContact = 'true';
  }

  this.navCtrl.push(EditContactPage, navObj);
}
```

This will allow you to add properties only if you want

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do it like this:

```
 addNewContact(event) {
    this.isLocalContact =false;
    if(isLocal) {
    this.isLocalContact =true;
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.navCtrl.push(EditContactPage, {
      isAdd: "true",
      isLocalContact : this.isLocalContact 
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Is else condition is needed here? I think we don't need else condition here. I'll edit  your answer mate